# How to overwrite form.html.twig using a custom module in drupal 9

Tags: templates, themes, drupal-9

I have created a custom form in a custom module but No matter what I do, the form is still is using core/themes/classy/templates/form/form.html.twig as the template. i've tried everything (that I can find) on the web but still no way to have own template applied. Please help!

Tried everything google can find me.
Just need my custom template to be applied instead of the default one.

My only requirement is for the module to contain its own theme templates and not rely on a specific theme.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried everything I could find, I resulted to overwriting the template in a new theme rather than in the module. I wanted something else, but better than continuing to waste time. I hope this helps someone else.